# .b3dm to regular 3d model converting

Tags: 3d, cesium, 3d-map, civil3d

I have never been using Cesium but recently found a web storage with multiple *.b3dm files. It looked like they represent buildings that could be helpful for my company. However I could not see if they can be converted to a regular *.dwg, *.obj, *.fbx or any other 3d model format.

Is it possible at all?

**UPD. 17.08.2020**
Here is a link to a sample `b3dm` file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sqWlowHWTxv-BdL_9SFFZarZXe79gi0s/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each b3dm file contains one [glTF](https://www.khronos.org/gltf/) file, most likely in GLB (glTF Binary) form.

I don't know if there's a tool to do this, but the glTF can be unwrapped from b3dm just by deleting the first several bytes from the start of the file, up until the first `glTF` ASCII marker.  That's the b3dm header, and it starts with ASCII bytes `b3dm`, and some bytes later you'll see the start of the .glb file, which starts with ASCII bytes `glTF`.

Strip off everything prior to the `glTF` magic number, and save the resulting file with a `.glb` extension.

Comment: thank for reply. I tried to skip 48 bytes while reading file in python and save the rest of it with `.glb` extension. But  still file is not readable. Could you please explain in details how to do it if possible?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it looks like the size of the b3dm header is somewhat variable.  You may have to scan for bytes that spell out `glTF` (with that capitalization) in ASCII, and strip off however many bytes come before that marker.

Comment: hey! I returned from vacation and saw your corrections. Unfortunately I cannot see how to do it correctly (I mean editing file in binary mode). If you tell your actions in details I would be very pleased. I also attached a sample file for you to be sure if this conversion is ever possible

Comment: the uploaded b3dm contains a glTF 1.0 model. Currently there are only glTF 2.0 viewers available.